# There are two partial differential equations arising from the same surface

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I was actually trying to find a partial differential equation for the surface, but I got two equations I don't know which is correct. Here are my steps:

The surface is $\log(au-1)=x+ay+b$, so $au = 1+e^{x+ay+b}$. In the picture below you can see I have got two equations, please help

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually both the PDEs are same, just eliminate $u_{y}$ and $u_{yy}$ from second PDE. Because $u_{y}^{2}=a^{2}u_{x}^{2}$ and $ u_{yy}=a^{2}u_{xx}. $

I will give you simple geometrical explanation, consider two differential equations $$ \frac{dy}{dx}=1 ~ \text{and} ~ \left ( \frac{dy}{dx} \right)^{2}=1 .$$ Then we need to find curve with slope $1$ and for second one, curve with slope $1$ or $-1$. Both the differential equations are different, one is linear and the other is nonlinear, but still have common solution $y=x.$ In other way you can say that for curve $y=x$, we have two different differential equations.

Comment: But the general solution of $u_x=u_{xx}$ is $u(x,y)=A+B(y)e^x$.

Comment: Can there be two PDE for the same surface how is this possible by the existence and unique theorem only one should exist

Comment: @TedShifrin Choose $A=1$ and $B(y)=\mathrm{e}^{ay+b}$.

Comment: @YASHWANTHM In PDEs we generally don't have existence and uniqueness theorem, we have this advantage only in ODEs.

Comment: @Manoj Kumar But the first is linear and the second is not linear how is this possible

Comment: Consider the PDEs $u_{x}=u_{xx}$ and $u_{y}^{2}=1$, then they both have common solution as $u=y$. But we don't know whether all the solutions are same.

Comment: @YASHWANTHM If you are familiar with Charpit method, then it also starts with the assumption: if two first order PDEs have common solution, and then they proceed further.